# What is the "Position" input of "Index of Nearest" node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In [Sample Nearest](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/sample/sample_nearest.html) node, I can plug an arbitrary vector or a field of arbitrary vectors. The docs seem to communicate the same thing about the [Index of Nearest](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/sample/index_of_nearest.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#bpy-types-geometrynodeindexofnearest):

> **Position**
>
> The position for each element to search. By default, this is the same as if the Position Node was connected.

I produced a simple example:

[image]

Since for each point, I'm looking for a point nearest to the position $<2, 2, 2>$, I expect to to find the first, index #0, vertex for all vertices but itself, which should find the 2nd nearest vertex, index #1. The viewer should say 1, 0, 0, not 2, 2, 1.

So what is the actual logic behind this socket?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to remember that the position it takes into account is **only** the one you input into the position field, [as apposed to the sample nearest that takes the position field at the context abd the physical position from the sampled geometry], so all the points are sampled here as if they all have the same position (at 2,2,2).

Comment: I was worried this might be the case - which is terrible, because I could easily use "set position" to achieve such result. Can you produce an example proving such behavior? How about producing the behavior intended by me - can it be done using this node, as opposed to (I imagine much slower) using a repeat zone?

Comment: seem to me that i don't get it. What sense does the input then make at all?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: did you try to add/multiply something? in my test it did change...nothing

Answer (score 1):

OK to prove I understood my lesson, I'll also write an answer.

## Basics

First a simple case just showing how the "nearest index" works in principle: it returns the index of the nearest element, not counting self.

You can see the 1st point, index #0, is on the left; the viewer displays $0$ as black.

The 2nd point (index #1, but it's irrelevant) is in middle and is controlled on the GIF. Only the value evaluated for this point is of interest in this presentation, so you can ignore the colors of other points. For the same reason, the spreadsheet shows only this point.

Finally, the 3rd point, index #2, is on the right; the viewer displays $2$ as white.

[image]

For the most part, the result of this experiment is very simple to understand: as the middle point moves to the left, the left point becomes the closer one, and so the middle point reports $0$ (the index of the left point) as the closest index and so becomes black. When the middle point moves to the right, it reports $2$ as the index of the nearest (right) point, and becomes white.

## Tie-breaker

However, when the middle point is at an equal distance to both other points, there's no valid answer on which of the two (in this case two; there could be more than 2 ex æquo winners) is closer. Usually the last sorting criterion is index, and so it's reasonable shmuel assumes here also the index is a tie-breaker, but at the same time is surprised the convention doesn't follow in the ascending/descending matter, and in the question the maximum index is picked.

Never assume. This is why I decided to investigate too.

In the GIF above, the point in middle, when it is in perfect middle, becomes black, so it picks the lowest index ($0$). Therefore **the tie-breaker is not index**.

At the same time we can say the tie-breaker is stable, deterministic, because when the point moves along $y$ axis, remaining at an equal distance to two other points, it remains black instead of blinking, proving the tie-breaker consistency:

[image]

I'm too lazy to read the Blender source - perhaps some kind of list of candidates from BVHtree is being processed, and once no more elements can be removed from the list, as all are at an equal distance to the evaluated point - the first element on the list is picked. If you think this could depend on order of sectors of the 3D space, rather than order of the elements, but the below experiment disproves it as well:

[image]

The tie-breaker could be something very technical like an ordering based on a hash of each element, so I think it's fair to just call it (deterministic) random…

## Radius

Gordon [why did you delete the answer??] introduced various radii in his points, so I just had to test this:

[image]

**Radii are irrelevant**. Points are dimensionless, and radius only affects how a point is displayed, not how close it is considered to be to other points. [Just to be clear: Gordon didn't claim radii are relevant to distance calculation, he used it for a different purpose].

## The actual answer

I suspected it, but didn't say so because I didn't want to suggest the answer I didn't want to hear… It doesn't work like "Sample Nearest", that allows a point to override the sampling position (from the default, self position), without affecting self position. Think about it, if you were sampling the same geometry from which you are sampling, and overriding the default "Position" input from current position to anything else, you would move the points rather than say from where you're sampling, and so you would always find yourself. Of course the flaw of this argument is that it's never "the same" geometry, as logically (an implementation may be different but will act as if this statement was true) geometry is passed by value, not reference -  each link makes a copy of geometry.

Here's two equivalent setups:

[image]

And so the "Position" input serves as a convenience feature that can save you up to 5 nodes, if you actually need to move those points, need that to be temporary, don't store the position for other reasons etc.

## Proof

Here's an expensive way to produce an empty geometry:

[image]

[image]

For a 1000 tries, a 1000 points with random positions, overridden to other random positions, found the same connection, so I think this proves those setups are equivalent.

## The Misconception

This is how I actually thought this works:

[image]

You may think: it would be a convenience feature for a similar number of nodes. There is however a crucial difference: in this case, these nodes are run as many times as many points there are. So if you have a completely reasonable number of 10 000 points, the algorithm could be maybe 10 times slower in the first case, but 10 000 faster in the second case. I understand, however, that it wouldn't be easy to implement it this way.

Comment: too much. (~15 character to comment)

Comment: did you know in blender 4.1 there is a number overlay, so you could have the Index displayed

Comment: @shmuel I divided it to sections so you can choose how much to read. Also I need to fix the last node tree, needs position/field switch based on the same "equal" selection

Comment: it's alright not too long. very nice . just skimmed it, but looks good. very nicely sized sections. very readable.

Comment: it's better than my answers

Comment: I'm sorry to say (_my_ bad): I still don't understand the actual aim of your question. I mean what you wanted to achieve using this index of nearest node?

Comment: @lemon if you look at this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/309536/60486 my first approach was to use the index of nearest. Here's the node setup at that moment: https://i.imgur.com/4zmapW0.png - looking at it after seeing the final solution probably makes it seem stupid, but that was my initial prototype: find the nearest point, but not from own position - from own position after subdivision - but not to own position after subdivision, just to own position before subdivision. I also gave another example under Gordon's answer but he removed it for some reason...

Comment: @lemon ... the example was: imagine that you want to find the nearest point to e.g. make a connection, that's exactly why you would use "index of nearest". But now imagine you want it to be weighed based on normal - you want the points to prefer points that are "in front" of them. A simple solution would be to adjust sampling position by adding a scaled normal to own position - but then the candidates are also moved, which you don't want...

Comment: Markus, ok. For information, this is a KDTree (similar as Python one, with the usage of filter option to eliminate self). If I read well here (not totally sure) https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/6e2624967150dff73f575623552ae923dd185197/source/blender/nodes/geometry/nodes/node_geo_index_of_nearest.cc#L84 it takes positions evaluated from the input field. So... no mystery about providing a constant value.